# Face normals to point to view

Tags: python

I require help with a script to make the face normals point to view when creating a plane. Blender seems to use coordinates and it's unpredictable.

```
import bpy

#select objects to make a face

bpy.data.objects['moving_object'].select_set(True)

obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects['moving_object']
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj


bpy.data.objects['fixed_object'].select_set(True)

obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects['fixed_object']
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj


bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')


bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add()


bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()


bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='MEDIAN')
```

Comment: Please post script.

Comment: There are two objects each containing 3 vertices. The script selects both objects then makes a face on each one. Depending on the angulation of the objects, the face normals are unpredictable. http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51558